# Records being shown by default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

i am newbie to MVC 3 and linq to sql, My code is running well except for one problem that when i first browse my page than it shows some records by default, why ?

[image]

after date searching etc all things appear correctly as i need but one problem that all records appear by default and also the text below SUBMIT button.

CODE:

```
public ActionResult ShowCalTextBox(String DateFrom, String DateTo) 
        {

            if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo == "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateFrom = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for"+" "+ DateFrom ;
                return View(EmpRec_DateFrom);

            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo != "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateTo = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for" + " " + DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_DateTo);
            }
            else if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo != "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_ByDate = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records from" + " " + DateFrom +" "+"to"+" "+DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_ByDate);
            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo == "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_Default = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "No date selection";
                return View(EmpRec_Default);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

VIEW:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowCalTextBox";
}

<h2>Search By Date</h2>
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCalTextBox", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
  <label id="lblFrom">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxFrom" name="DateFrom" />
  <label id="lblTo">To</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxTo" name="DateTo"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitDate" name="btnSubmit">Submit</button>  
}
</div>

<div>
 <h4>@ViewBag.Dates</h4>
 <br />
 @{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model);

  }
 @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First time GET Operation will make DateFrom and DateTo will be NULLs**, so that will execute the below code -

```
    else if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo != "") 
    {
        IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_ByDate = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, DateTo).ToList();
        ViewBag.Dates = "Records from" + " " + DateFrom +" "+"to"+" "+DateTo;
        return View(EmpRec_ByDate);
    }
```

Its better you check for String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() for all the inputs. Like shown below -

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateFrom) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateTo))
```

Comment: why it would be executed ? i clearly have mentioned that not equal to null, so why it would be executed in NULLS case ?

Comment: @Evilrising, you are only checking for string empty (!= ""), you need to check for nulls too.

Comment: not working sie, tried your code, could you point out the right way ?

Comment: try this -  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateFrom) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DateTo)), I forgot to include ! for the second condition. I updated my answer.

Comment: error: System.InvalidOperationException: A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

Comment: you might have to check for null at  var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model);, because in GET case you will are only returning View(); and there is no Model Data. So i think it is complaining that. Or else simply initiate a Model in controller action and set it to null, then check for null at the time of webgrid binding.